# How do I add solution build configurations into TFS source control?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am setting up some solutions/projects for my small team here however the solution/project build configurations don't seem to go into TFS.

When we download the solution on another computer? They are empty.
Also, sometimes on the same computer, they just disappear alltogether?

Any ideas how to add this into source control? When I change them, there doesn't appear to be any pending files in the solution to check into source control.

Answer (score 1):

The build configuration information is saved in the solution file. When you add/update the configuration from "Configuration Manager", the solution file will be updated accordingly and the changes will be displayed in "Pending Changes". Check in the pending changes will sync the configuration update to Source Control. Following is a screenshot for configuration change:
[image]

Comment: I had a similar concern in that I added a new configuration but there were no changes detecting in source control.

What caught me out was that you have to save the changes to the solution and project files.  Either Building which forces a save or pressing the Save All button.  There wasn't anything visual to suggest there were dirty files.